# Adding 1/4th to a Twitter Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have three columns like this in a row:

```
<div class="col-lg-.5 side-nav"></div>
<div class="col-lg-8.25 canvas"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3.25 persistent"></div>'
```

.5 + 8.25 + 3.25 = 12, but my columns are not showing up correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are no classes like these. Only integers col-X-1 to col-X-12 by default.

Comment: I see. What would be a possible solution then?

Comment: dots `.` are also not valid in class names, you can add your own class names and add it to the css

Comment: use col-lg-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-3

Comment: The problem is that col-lg-1 takes up 8.333% of the screen, and half of that would be ideal.

Comment: then create your own class according to your requirement in css  file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to have half of the col-lg-1 you can use this

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div> <!-- here you have half of col-lg-1 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest approach to what you want. I was about to comment the same thing but yuyokk beat me to it. +1

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where I can see the col-lg-.5 following by the col-lg-8.25 ? In your answer, I don't see how its possible... I see a 0.5 col, with a 0.5 blank...

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9af3827s/ but please note that I use col-xs-* to make it visible it on that small jsfiddle window

Comment: In fact I just wanna say, that the 0.5 is not followed by the other col... There is white space : https://jsfiddle.net/9af3827s/1/ . Use Xs col make it work for higher too, not inverse

Comment: it is a default margin and padding applied to all col- classes in bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

It can't be correct.
Bootstrap only contains col-md-integer

You can try

```
Col-lg-1
Col-lg-8
Col-lg-3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have something else than 12 columns :

Just customize it : `@grid-columns` : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

```
12 x 4 = 48 cols
```

so just use a bootstrap customized with **48 cols**.